# What is the 'correct' way of using homebrew to enable successful homebrew node installation

Tags: node.js, permissions, installation, homebrew

I'm setting up a developer environment on OSX and want to use homebrew to manage installs. I am going on the premise that my regular dev account should not be an admin account and then I have setup an additional admin account for the purposes of performing homebrew installs. I think this is the safest way to use homebrew and to avoid sudo as per the recommendation.
I am now having problems installing node/npm and am wary and hesitant of the changes I need to make to fix it.

(for the purposes of this question, dev account=kramer, admin account=admin).

I installed homebrew using as my admin account.

If I ls my /usr/local/Cellar directory I see:

> drwxr-xr-x  2 Kramer  admin  68 26 Jul 12:47 /usr/local/Cellar

which shows that only the owner Kramer has write permissions to it.

Then if I ls my /usr/local directory is see:

> drwxrwxr-x  18 admin  admin  612 26 Jul 12:47 /usr/local

which shows that its owned by admin (and in the admin group).

If I try to install node as Kramer using brew install node:

> Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/Library/Locks/node.brewing

If I try to install node as admin (su admin, not sudo) using the same command I get:

> Error: Cannot write to /usr/local/Cellar

I want to do this the right way, and not implement hacks. I thought I should be ok to use my admin account any time that I want to install anything with homebrew, and then revert back to my regular account Kramer for everyday coding. Am I wrong about this? Which account should be the owner of /usr/local/Cellar and /usr/local for me to achieve this?

Should /usr/local/Cellar owner be changed to admin (assuming I do installs with the admin account)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally use one account for dev and homebrew. [You don't need](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad-) `sudo` for homebrew installation or for further software installation like node or php.

Specifically for node.js you can use https://github.com/tj/n. It installs node binary in `/usr/local/bin` and it's pretty easy to control/update node.js version with it.